# Angular 4 how to open new tab on button click and set variable in session. And prevent current page from freezing

Tags: angular

**.html file :-**

```
<button type="button" (click)="goToEditDestinationByDestinationId($event,destination_id)" class="icon-btn-box"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></button>
```

**.ts file :-**

```
goToEditDestinationByDestinationId(event, destination_id) {
    event.preventDefault();

    sessionStorage.setItem("destination_id",destination_id);
    this.destinationService.setDestinationId(destination_id);
    let editURL = window.location.origin + "/#/destination/editdestination";
    window.open(editURL, '_blank');
  }
```

On button click it opens new tab and current page freezes and then few seconds later both tab crashes. I am setting a session variable before opening new tab so that it can fetch data from DB related to that data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with this **destinationService** which you are using.

```
this.destinationService.setDestinationId(destination_id);
```

So better debug from the beginning of the function **goToEditDestinationByDestinationId** and **setDestinationId** line by line until the tab freezes. You might find the bug on the way.

Comment: I removed that line but it is still freezing and new tab is crashing after few seconds. What above line doing is setting a variable in a service and that service is imported in another component so that it can get that value and fetch data from DB with respect to that value.

Comment: Did you try debugging line by line? If no you should. Might be the problem is with the page you opened in the new tab. **"/#/destination/editdestination"**

Comment: Yes, I did. The issue is in the last line i.e window.open(editURL, '_blank');. One more thing is when new tab is opened I also want to set a session variable so that it can retrieve data with respect to that variable data.